# Finding position of the last non-blank cell in above row

Tags: excel

I have a row which looks something like this;

```
A1; test1
B1; -
C1; -
D1; test2
E1; -
F1; test1
G1; -
H1; -
I1; -
J1; -
K1; test2
L1; -
M1; test1
```

Where test1/2 can be either words or numbers and "-" are blank cells. The number of blank cells between each value can vary.

What I'm trying to do in the row below is return the last non-blank value from the left if the cell directly above is blank.

So the row below would look like;

```
test1, test1, test1, test1, *test2,test2,test2,* test1...
```

I've tried using various lookups/matches to try and return the position of the cell it needs to return, but lookup is inconsistent and match will only return the first one.

Can anyone help me with a formula that can be used starting in cell A1 and dragged across the rest of the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for either text strings or numbers that are impossible to match using a non-sorted approximate lookup with a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). The [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) can provide the greater of the two and [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can supply zeroes in case of non-matches.

[image: Return last known text or number]

The formula in A2 is,

```
=INDEX(1:1, MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99, $A1:A1), 0), IFERROR(MATCH("zzz", $A1:A1), 0)))
```

Fill right as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, entered as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER):

```
=INDEX(YourRange,MAX(IF(ISBLANK(YourRange),"blank",COLUMN(YourRange))))
```

where `YourRange` is say A1:M1, or 1:1 if you want to analyze all of row 1.

Hope that helps